# Doctrine 1 and multiple primary keys, is it possible?

Tags: php, doctrine

Can i have multiple primary keys with Doctrine 1? If not, any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

There are always 1 primary key in table (Its Databases' restriction)
You can use Unique keys instead( I don't know how about unique key support in doctrine. Visit manual on [Doctrine site](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) )

Answer (score 0):

The doctrine manuals doesn't really mention anything about this, but Symfony (1.2) briefly [covers this](http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/06-Working-With-Data#chapter_06_sub_finders) in their manual (symfony uses doctrine as their default ORM).

```
$userGroup = Doctrine::getTable('UserGroup')->find(array(1, 2));
```

I can't think of why doctrine wouldn't support composite primary keys, since you can declare models for junction table, which effectively consists of composite primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But It does not have a lot of documentation. For example, if we want the entity User to have many Locations, and the Locations to have many Users, then your need something like this:

In the setup method of your User model you put this:

```
$this->hasMany('Location as Locations', array(
    'refClass' => 'UserLocation', //Refering to the relation table
    'local' => 'user_id', //the user id in the realtion table
    'foreign' => 'location_id' //the location id in the relation table
));
```

In the setup method of the location model you put this:

```
$this->hasMany('User as Users', array(
    'refClass' => 'UserLocation',
    'local' => 'location_id',
    'foreign' => 'user_id'
));
```

In the setup method of the many to many relation model (UserLocation) you can put this:

```
$this->hasMany('User', array(
     'local' => 'user_id',
     'foreign' => 'id'));

$this->hasMany('Location', array(
     'local' => 'location_id',
     'foreign' => 'id'));
```

Now, if you want to do a Doctrine_Query, and get all the users from the location id: 12, it would be something like:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select("u.*")
     ->from('User u')
     ->leftJoin("u.UserLocation ul") 
     ->where('ul.location_id = ?',12);
```

If you are inserting a user remember to create the UserLocation objetct as well, something like this:

```
$userLocation = new UserLocation();
$userLocation->location_id = $locationId;
$userLocation->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$userLocation->user_id = $user->id; //from the user you created before
$userLocation->save();
```